# sorting and printing elements of array prints out garbage

Tags: c, arrays

Hi can someone help me with the logical error in my code, i want to print out some float numbers by arrays but when i enter the numbers it prints out garbage and 0.000000 or else.

here is my code and i have defined SIZE 4 just to make it easier:

```
int main(){
double array1[SIZE];

printf("\n Enter the elements of Array 1: ");
get_value(array1);
printf("\n\n Elements of Array 1: ");
print_value(array1, SIZE);
}
```

then there are my functions

```
void get_value(double arr[]){
int i, j;
for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
    j = i + 1;
    printf("\n Enter element %d: ", j);
    scanf("%f", &arr[i]);
}


void print_value(double arr[], int n){
int i;
printf("{ ");
for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
    printf("%f ", arr[i]);
}
printf("}");

void function_sort(double arr[] = {0}){
int i, j, temp, swapping;
for (i = 1; i < SIZE; i++){
    swapping = 0;
    for (j = 0; j < SIZE - i; j++){
        if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1]){
            temp = arr[j];
            arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
            arr[j + 1] = temp;
            swapping = 1;
        }
    }
    if (swapping == 0){
        break;
    }
}
```

}

and the output is something like this :

```
 Enter the elements of Array 1:


Enter element 1: 1.5

 Enter element 2: 2.5

 Enter element 3: 3.25

 Enter element 4: 2.25


 Elements of Array 1: { 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 321179424811157990000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.000000 }
Sorted elements of Array 1: { 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 321179424811157990000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000.000000 }
```

Comment: Honestly that's a terrible piece of indentation and formatting

Comment: and where exactly are you calling `function_sort`?

Comment: @potato i am sorry i am newbie

Comment: @babon well it really doesnt matter but it is in my main and after the elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scanf("%lf", &arr[i]);` Use the correct format specifier otherwise it is an error.(Mandatory - `%f` can cause erroneous scanning of input).

Also for printing the result would be `printf("%lf",arr[i])`. (Not mandatory -`%f` also works).

Bubble sort code:-

```
int flag = 1;
for (size_t i = n - 1; flag && i >= 0; i--){
  flag = 0;
  for (size_t j = 0; j < i; j++){
    if (a[j] > a[j + 1]) {
      int temp = a[j];
      a[j] = a[j + 1];
      a[j + 1] = temp;
      flag = 1;
    }
  }
}
```

<sup>Vlad's comment here were given to the reply of this code [Rosetta Code for Bubble sort](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms/Bubble_sort). Now the code has some faults that it is repetitively doing the comparison in the inner loop. The array is not being partitioned into sorted part and unsorted part as it should.</sup>

Comment: It is the worst code of the bubble sort I have seen.

Comment: For starters the size of the array shall heave the type size_t. The variables should be declared in the scope where they are used.  The selection of the identifier "s" is unclear. The inner loop traverses all elements

Comment: I do not know who is Rosetta. But it is evident that he is unable to write a good code. He demonstrates how code should not be written.

Comment: The code you showed is not the bubble sort. I am sorry but this question is not interesting for me.

Comment: Thank you that solved my problem and taught me something cool, i really appreciate it.

Comment: @coderredoc It is a bad idea to remove the comments because they are important.